# Why is the output not what is expected?

Tags: java

This code is supposed to take the amount due for an item and the amount paid. Then find the change in coins and dollars. When ever I put due: 41.35 and received: 50.00, I get 8 dollars, 2 quarters, 1, dime, 0 nickels, 4 pennies. In reality, it should be 8 dollars, 2 quarters, 1, dime, 1 nickel, 0 pennies.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Cashier {
    private double amountDue;
    private double amountReceived;
    private int dollars = 0;
    private int quarters = 0;
    private int dimes = 0;
    private int nickels = 0;
    private int pennies = 0;
    private double toConvert;

    public Cashier(double due, double received){
        amountDue = due;
        amountReceived = received;
        toConvert = received - due;
    }
    public int getDollars(){
        dollars = (int)toConvert;
        toConvert -= dollars;
        return dollars;
    }
    public int getQuarters(){
        quarters = (int)(toConvert/.25);
        toConvert -= (.25 * quarters);
        return quarters;
    }
    public int getDimes(){
        dimes = (int)(toConvert/0.1);
        toConvert -= (.1 * dimes);
        return dimes;
    }
    public int getNickels(){
        nickels = (int)(toConvert/0.05);
        toConvert -= (0.05 * nickels);
        return nickels;
    }
    public int getPennies(){
        pennies = (int)(toConvert/0.01);
        toConvert -= (0.01 * pennies);
        return pennies;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner ask = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Amount Due: ");
        double amtDue = ask.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter Amount Received: ");
        double amtReceived = ask.nextDouble();

        Cashier one = new Cashier(amtDue, amtReceived);
        System.out.println("Dollars = " + one.getDollars());
        System.out.println("Quarters = " + one.getQuarters());
        System.out.println("Dimes = " + one.getDimes());
        System.out.println("Nickels = " + one.getNickels());
        System.out.println("Pennies = " + one.getPennies());

    }

}
```

Comment: You are running into [floating point rounding errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/1270789). The simplest way would be to immediately convert the dollar `amntDue` into cents and store the result in an integer - `int centsDue = (int) Math.round(amntDue * 100);` - and use that throughout the code.

Comment: In concrete terms, if you run this case under a debugger, by the time you get to `getNickels()` the value of `toConvert` is 0.04999999999999857. So `toConvert/0.05` is 0.9999999999999715, which when truncated to an `int` is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem you ran into here. Here's how I went about figuring it out. First thing I did was try printing the amount of change left to break down after you ran each function. I changed the main function to look like this:

NOTE: I had to change `toConvert` to `static` to use it in the main function

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner ask = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Amount Due: ");
    double amtDue = ask.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter Amount Received: ");
    double amtReceived = ask.nextDouble();

    TestA one = new TestA(amtDue, amtReceived);
    System.out.println("change due: " + toConvert);
    System.out.println("Dollars = " + one.getDollars());
    System.out.println("change due: " + toConvert);
    System.out.println("Quarters = " + one.getQuarters());
    System.out.println("change due: " + toConvert);
    System.out.println("Dimes = " + one.getDimes());
    System.out.println("change due: " + toConvert);
    System.out.println("Nickels = " + one.getNickels());
    System.out.println("change due: " + toConvert);
    System.out.println("Pennies = " + one.getPennies());
    System.out.println("change due: " + toConvert);
}
```

The output looked like this:

```
Enter Amount Due: 41.35
Enter Amount Received: 50.00
change: 8.649999999999999
Dollars = 8
change: 0.6499999999999986
Quarters = 2
change: 0.14999999999999858
Dimes = 1
change: 0.04999999999999857
Nickels = 0
change: 0.04999999999999857
Pennies = 4
change: 0.009999999999998573
```

This told me that the issue was in rounding your `double` values. The change should have been `8.65` in the first part if the program was running correctly. This has to do with how `double` values are stored on the hardware and its a pretty confusing topic(to me, at least).

Change the values to `float` instead of `double` and it'll work fine. There's info out there on this website and others about rounding `double` values and there are ways around it like formatting to x number of decimals and rounding and such but  think changing it to `float` is an easier avenue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to designate the input in terms of cents, which is the smallest form of currency you can accept. Otherwise, for a charge of 70¢, given 3 quarters, your code would try to it convert it to dollars.

The code is very simple, and can be written as a single recursive function without the need for dozens of special methods. I won't do it for you, but the following should give you a very good idea.

```
865 / 100 = 8
65 / 25 = 2
15 / 10 = 1
5 / 5 = 1
0 / 1 = 0
```

Comment: What do you mean by "for a charge of 70¢, given 3 quarters, your code would try to it convert it to dollars"? The original code handles that particular case correctly.

Comment: @tgtdavies It doesn’t. What happens if you input 3? Is 3 equal to $3, 75c or 3c? There needs to be a way to indicate the denominations, just like we do for dates in ISO-8601 format.

Comment: The original code uses dollars. If you give it 0.7 and 0.75 is correctly gives change of 1 nickel.

Comment: So when does this floating error occur? Every time you do arithmetic operations with two doubles? When I do something like System.out.println(5.6-1.1);, it gives 4.5. Then why is it that my problem goes to 8.64999999999?

Comment: @BobChan Someone already provided a link to the [most popular SO post on fp math](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/839733). Read it.

Answer (score -1):

After this step : toConvert = received - due;
The toConvert amount turns to 8.649999999999999
This requires an additional step to the round of decimal to two places so the amount turns 8.65
change your Cashier funtion to this:

```
public Cashier(double due, double received){
    amountDue = due;
    amountReceived = received;
    double num = received - due;
    toConvert = Math.round(num * 100.0) / 100.0;
    System.out.println(toConvert);
}
```

This solution works temporary while working with a double. But converting figure to cents and using arithmetic solve is the right way.

Comment: The rounding problems can happen in any of the coin conversion steps. As others have said, converting the figures to cents and using integer arithmetic is the correct solution.

Comment: Your solution to round the toConvert to 8.65 fixed the problem. Thank you. So when does this floating error occur? Every time you do arithmetic operations with two doubles? When I do something like System.out.println(5.6-1.1);, it gives 4.5. Then why is it that my problem goes to 8.64999999999?